# Remove rows that contain values above a certain cut point in R

Tags: r, graph, time-series, outliers

[image: time-series plot]

Hi, I have plotted a time-series for a bunch of objects monitored on a specific variable over 12 hours. I want to remove all objects that contain values above `10` on the y-axis of the graph above. Is that even possible? Any pointers would help me much. Thanks.

Here's a dput of a part of my data:

```
test <- structure(list(hr3 = c(-0.448581004620338, 1.85091950824544, 
-0.388161362087543, -0.665380898414483, -0.277984366880682, -0.437918714761609, 
0.0418843288811726, -0.516108840392285, -0.76134150714304, -0.3348499127939, 
0.884205227720723, -0.014981217032046), hr4 = c(-0.428512239173087, 
1.95372170393779, -0.366683266603797, -0.646732142358816, -0.0320794150523447, 
-0.47943021658309, -0.315765289193793, -0.533985192379523, -0.537622190765952, 
0.0261125591305165, 0.935362155737723, -0.0138944231202006), 
hr5 = c(-0.556293173068285, 1.97570442413855, -0.393521898962132, 
-0.668424495230302, -0.219899206582235, -0.545441754794542, 
-0.527356057671636, -0.111385023844799, -0.581613149040354, 
1.05695101029493, 2.39890973681455, 0.0260662742892864), 
hr6 = c(0.141994463541292, 1.72026989695927, -0.433453508984239, 
-0.416627544875305, -0.181064047350234, -0.423357930518879, 
-0.48393140131104, -0.564696029033921, -0.749781634232192, 
0.52562644522498, 2.86107026354497, -0.0733778770530584), 
hr7 = c(-0.0818711569624052, 2.11985518432835, -0.373315076988859, 
-0.394510998445328, -0.375964567170917, -0.595872252281787, 
-0.577325821007376, -0.656810526469136, 0.180428371061403, 
0.143335508512581, 0.654687113649904, -0.285881900980923), 
hr8 = c(-0.474931311491395, 1.42292037404823, -0.37784044340877, 
-0.788186753795715, -0.526224600289764, -0.806505785509418, 
-0.766203915739272, -0.44012515123536, -0.474931311491395, 
-0.526224600289764, 0.0325058669781751, -0.471267505148655
), hr9 = c(-0.621770802068411, 0.401530426081227, -0.358586729853952, 
-0.304911030915477, -0.268550073570059, -0.654668811095218, 
-0.791455269680364, -0.822621804547866, -0.644279966139384, 
-0.491910240120487, -0.117911821710467, -0.384558842243537
), hr10 = c(-0.327619749398401, 0.462060915872808, 0.631788660670919, 
-0.611690395955239, -0.375858161077864, -0.77963153291337, 
-0.46518855307687, -0.78499135643331, -0.733179729073887, 
-0.427669788437288, 0.0118357401978198, 0.521018974592152
), hr11 = c(0.196841618716218, 0.58650231756246, -0.124164576047591, 
-0.562068980465273, -0.506403166344381, -0.756899329888394, 
-0.239207258564101, -0.756899329888394, -0.320850452608075, 
-0.189108025855298, 0.135609223183237, 0.126331587496421), 
hr12 = c(-0.336881803222796, 0.619313666511149, 3.66262655713023, 
-0.713215763198405, -0.177515891600472, -0.630652700550695, 
-0.254318740575086, -0.742016831563885, -0.44248572056289, 
-0.200556746292856, 0.212258566945695, 0.943805703428894), 
hr13 = c(-0.359473487083687, 0.577779602110567, -0.333386919988817, 
-0.771268581938419, 0.480886638615336, -0.707915490422307, 
-0.311027005336072, -0.761951950833109, -0.34456687731519, 
-0.56257604517946, 0.0821348273080387, 0.585232906994815), 
hr14 = c(-0.40294783799287, 0.573856351285527, -0.616102452351533, 
-0.758823368052551, 0.130865457096652, -0.773651515138371, 
-0.313978955477949, -0.771797996752644, -0.623516525894443, 
-0.562350419165435, 0.0696993503676446, -0.160136929462566
)), .Names = c("hr3", "hr4", "hr5", "hr6", "hr7", "hr8", 
"hr9", "hr10", "hr11", "hr12", "hr13", "hr14"), row.names = c("400", 
"401", "402", "403", "404", "405", "406", "407", "408", "409", 
"410", "411"), class = "data.frame")
```

and code I used to make the plot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
test$id = rownames(test)

mm = melt(test, id='id')

ggplot(mm)+geom_line(aes(x=variable, y=value, group=id, color=id))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). What does your input data look like? What code are you using to create this plot? Do you want to remove them from the data set or just the plot?

Comment: @MrFlick oh yes, sorry, I'll add sample dataset in a sec, and ggplot code. I want to remove them from my data since they seem to be outliers. Thanks.

Comment: You could use `subset` function on the melted dataset.

Comment: @R.L. thank you… just checked out the `subset()` function. How do I make it select all rows which contain columns with `values > 10` or select all rows that have `values < 10` across all columns?? from what I can see it only allows you to specify ranges for a single column, e.g. `hr3 > 10` instead of `hr3, hr4, hr5… hr14 > 10`

Comment: you can chain multiple conditions like: `subset(data , col1 > 10 | col2 < 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are no values above 10 in your test dataset, but let we instead drop values above to, you can either do it in the wide format with

```
lt2 <- test[rowSums(test[, 1:12]>2)==0, ]
```

or you can do it in the tall format with

```
mlt2 <- mm[with(mm, ave(value, id, FUN=max))<2, ]
```

both of those should drop all observations for individuals with any value >2.

Comment: works perfectly. thanks very much. please do you mind explaining a bit why we have the `rowSums()` and `ave()` functions?? because as far as the question goes we're not trying to get averages nor row summations??!! thanks!!